# Voice Memos on the iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, voice-memo

iPhones have a dedicated Voice Memos app. iPads don't, despite running the same OS and also featuring a built-in microphone.

Since the answer to 1 is probably "no", what current alternatives do people use? 
(ideally free simple app that works the same way like Voice Memos on the iPhone)

Comment: The policy on software recommendation has changed since the original question was posted, so I think it's best to close this one as a duplicate. If you are looking for Voice Memo alternatives for an iPad, a simple search in the App Store will yield more results than any inquiry on AD ever will.

Comment: Thank you @patrix for pointing to the other question. I had found it and had already linked to it in a comment but that comment seems to have been deleted somehow.  My main reason for posting was that that question is 4 years old and there are tons of new apps.  So precisely because an App Store search will give so many results, I was hoping to get feedback, what are currently the apps that most faithfully replicate the iPhone Voice Memos app, before starting to download a bunch of apps.

Comment: @patrix  Or maybe it's better to edit the linked question to attract some new answers with up to date info?  I'm not sure what would be the appropriate way of going about it.

Comment: I've deleted the comments because the things discussed are better suited for Meta. As for editing the original question, please keep in mind that software recommendation questions are generally considered to be off-topic nowadays (mainly because there usually is no clear answer and it tends to attract spam and other unwanted content). A lot of voice memo apps are free, why not give some of them a try? You might even find one with features you didn't think about but are actually helpful.

Comment: Also, when we close software recommendation questions, the close reason says *"... questions asking to recommend or find off-site resources (Mac/book/software/tutorial) are off-topic for Ask Different as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, edit to clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it."*. Research in this case is looking at the offerings in the store as well as trying a few google searches.

Comment: @patrix I totally understand the urge to keep the site off spam. As for trying some of the apps myself, it's probably just my personal preference, but I really dislike downloading additional apps from the app store. I prefer to just stick with what Apple put there as it suits most of my needs—my iPad only has 7 third party apps so far, and I have it for almost a year now. So I had just hoped to get an answer telling me of all the memo apps on the store, X and Y are the ones that do the job of Voice memos best – and my choice is down to two.

Comment: @patrix I thought there must have been people out there wanting to do recordings on the iPad and already having tried different apps, so I had hoped to profit from their experience.  I tried a number of online searches and went to a couple of different websites, but since I really couldn't find any good and informed discussions comparing different apps anywhere on the web, I decided I'd ask my own question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44561/discussion-between-patrix-and-jan).

Comment: I'm going to put a lock on this. Let's discuss in meta why we ask for one question per question. This is a great example of how multiple threads, multiple issues makes answering / finding / moderating problematic.

Answer (score 0):

1. There are no clones of the voice memos app for iPad.
2. Options include:

   - [Microsoft Onenote](https://appsto.re/ca/UjIDy.i)     (this one is a little more complex, and has different features, including adding additional photos, videos, lists, etc.)
   - [Audio Memos Free - The Voice Recorder by Imesart S.a.r.l.](https://appsto.re/ca/ze9hs.i) (Just voice memos - not a ported version)